# How can I format the XML response of my REST web service?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, rest

I am playing around with [this simple tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255684/Create-and-Consume-RESTFul-Service-in-NET-Framewor) in C# and here is the kind of XML you can GET.

```
    <Person xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RESTfulDemo" 
      xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Age>23</Age>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>Bob Kohler</Name>
    </Person>
```

Here is the Person.cs class :

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    namespace RESTfulDemo
    {   

      [DataContract]
      public class Person
      {
         [DataMember]
         public string ID;

         [DataMember]
         public string Name;

         [DataMember]
         public string Age;
      }
    }
```

1) How should can I add attributes / Prefixes in my XML for each data member ?

2) How can I set the heading of my XML to this (or anything else) :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Comment: Adding the doctype is possible but requires some coding - see http://shevaspace.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/include-xml-declaration-in-wcf-restful.html. For 1) You'll have to look at overriding the XmlSerialization

Comment: Thanks @Dash, your link is very worth looking at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is what I did to overcome this problem. The solution does not involve Serialization but at least it enables to format the response like you want.

- (1) Put XElement from System.xml.linq as return type of each method and build the xml with the XElement class in each method.
- (2) Use exactly [the code provided here](http://shevaspace.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/include-xml-declaration-in-wcf-restful.html)  to add the xml declaration on top of your xml response. Thanks to @Dash for the link.

Answer (score 0):

question 2) can be done when initializing a document:

```
XDocument document = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", "yes"));
```

as for question 1), from what I have understood, if you have such XML file:

```
<CATALOG>
  <CD>
    <TITLE> ... </TITLE>
    <ARTIST> ... </ARTIST>
    <YEAR> ... </YEAR>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

and you need to add an attribute `"id"` for the `CD` node, 
               (where the id is automatically incremented)

```
XmlNodeList list = document.GetElementsByTagName("CATALOG");
int i = 0;

foreach (XmlNode CD in list)
  {
    i++;
    XmlAttribute idAttr = document.CreateAttribute("id");
    idAttr.Value = i.ToString();
    CD.Attributes.Append(idAttr); //to append the created attribute and its value to the CD node
  }
```

Comment: The problem is I don't handle the document... the return type of GetPerson() is Person. The service returns a Person but build the xml just before sending it. So where should I use this kind of code ?

Comment: well, I didn't really understand, but maybe this post will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11897491/1522782

Comment: Sorry no, since I use serialization here (from what I understand, I might be wrong) at no point I do have a hold of the response message of the webservice as an xml node.